# Add new reference block and add content using layout update from cms page

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.8

I have created a new reference by follow any google tutorial and want to upload the content from cms page layout upadte .please help.

```
http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/custom-reference-structural-block/
```

I have used these link to create a new reference.

Comment: Was my answer useful? Did you solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

Within your static block, you can call the block of your layout update with following code:

```
{{block type="core/template" name="reference.block.name" template="myfolder/templatefile.phtml"}}
```